# Ansible custom module execute on local reports "raise BadZipFile" error

Tags: ansible, module

In order to collect some system info to record to a local excel. I have tried to write a ansible custom module. Here is the code:

```py
#!/usr/bin/python3

from ansible.module_utils.basic import AnsibleModule
from openpyxl import Workbook, load_workbook


def main():
    module = AnsibleModule(argument_spec=dict(headers=dict(type='str', required=True),
                                              file=dict(type='path', required=True),
                                              custom_data=dict(type='str', required=True)))

    headers = module.params['headers'].split(',')
    file_path = module.params['file']
    custom_data = module.params['custom_data'].split(',')

    workbook = None
    try:
        workbook = load_workbook(file_path)
    except FileNotFoundError:
        workbook = Workbook()
        sheet = workbook.active
        sheet.append(headers)
    else:
        sheet = workbook.active
        first_row = sheet[1]
        if not all(cell.value == header for cell, header in zip(first_row, headers)):
            sheet.insert_rows(1)
            for i, header in enumerate(headers):
                sheet.cell(row=1, column=i + 1, value=header)
        sheet.delete_rows(2, sheet.max_row)

    sheet.append(custom_data)

    workbook.save(file_path)

    result = dict(changed=True, msg="Data recorded to Excel file.", file_path=file_path)

    module.exit_json(**result)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

But when I use this module in my playbook. It just can collect first host successfully. Others will get the error like this:

```
"FAILED! => {"changed": false, "module_stderr": "Traceback (most recent call last):
  File \"/home/Kaol/.ansible/tmp/ansible-tmp-1682669365.732851-8192830-43745624433561/AnsiballZ_excel_record.py\", line 102, in <module>
    _ansiballz_main()
  File \"/home/Kaol/.ansible/tmp/ansible-tmp-1682669365.732851-8192830-43745624433561/AnsiballZ_excel_record.py\", line 94, in _ansiballz_main
    invoke_module(zipped_mod, temp_path, ANSIBALLZ_PARAMS)
  File \"/home/Kaol/.ansible/tmp/ansible-tmp-1682669365.732851-8192830-43745624433561/AnsiballZ_excel_record.py\", line 40, in invoke_module
    runpy.run_module(mod_name='ansible.modules.excel_record', init_globals=None, run_name='__main__', alter_sys=True)
  File \"/opt/freeware/lib64/python3.7/runpy.py\", line 205, in run_module
    return _run_module_code(code, init_globals, run_name, mod_spec)
  File \"/opt/freeware/lib64/python3.7/runpy.py\", line 96, in _run_module_code
    mod_name, mod_spec, pkg_name, script_name)
  File \"/opt/freeware/lib64/python3.7/runpy.py\", line 85, in _run_code
    exec(code, run_globals)
  File \"/tmp/ansible_excel_record_payload_x0_h65lp/ansible_excel_record_payload.zip/ansible/modules/excel_record.py\", line 42, in <module>
  File \"/tmp/ansible_excel_record_payload_x0_h65lp/ansible_excel_record_payload.zip/ansible/modules/excel_record.py\", line 18, in main
  File \"/opt/freeware/lib/python3.7/site-packages/openpyxl/reader/excel.py\", line 345, in load_workbook
    data_only, keep_links, rich_text)
  File \"/opt/freeware/lib/python3.7/site-packages/openpyxl/reader/excel.py\", line 123, in __init__
    self.archive = _validate_archive(fn)
  File \"/opt/freeware/lib/python3.7/site-packages/openpyxl/reader/excel.py\", line 95, in _validate_archive
    archive = ZipFile(filename, 'r')
  File \"/opt/freeware/lib64/python3.7/zipfile.py\", line 1258, in __init__
    self._RealGetContents()
  File \"/opt/freeware/lib64/python3.7/zipfile.py\", line 1325, in _RealGetContents
    raise BadZipFile(\"File is not a zip file\")
zipfile.BadZipFile: File is not a zip file
", "module_stdout": "", "msg": "MODULE FAILURE
See stdout/stderr for the exact error", "rc": 1}"
```

And my playbook like this:

```yaml
---
- name: 'Collect OS info to excel'
  hosts: all
  gather_facts: yes
  tasks:
    - name: 'Collect OS info'
      excel_record:
        headers: 'Hostname,IP,OS,OS Version'
        file: '/tmp/fuhua/ansible/OS_info.xlsx'
        custom_data: '{{ ansible_hostname }},{{ ansible_default_ipv4.address }},{{ ansible_distribution }},{{ ansible_distribution_version }}'
      delegate_to: localhost
```

I have no idea what cause this error. Why does it check the zip file after first running? How could I fix it?

And is there a way to avoid using `delegate_to: localhost` to save the excel to the local?